# How to assign a JSON object as github action output variable

Tags: github-actions

I have the below code to read a JSON and get the array element in the json and assign it to github output variable

```
{
  "appname": "apple",
  "category": "fruit",
  "test": [
    {
      "workdir": "work1",
      "tesdir": "test1",
      "setdata": {
        "set1": "value1",
        "set2": "value2"
      }
     },
     {
      "workdir": "work2",
      "tesdir": "test2",
      "setdata": {
        "set1": "value3",
        "set2": "value4"
      }
   }
  ]
}
```

```
$objects = @()          
          for ($i = 0; $i -lt $json.test.Count; $i++) {                  
            $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
             "build$($i + 1)" = $json.test[$i]    
             }
            $jsonObjects = $object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
             switch ( $($i + 1))
            {
              1 { echo "build1=$jsonObjects" >>  $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT}
              2 { echo "build2=$jsonObjects" >>  $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT }           
            }
          }
```

But  i am getting error

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Invalid format '    "build_dir1":  {'
```

Any help please?

Comment: $objects = @()          
          for ($i = 0; $i -lt $json.test.Count; $i++) {                  
            $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
             "build$($i + 1)" = $json.test[$i]    
             }
            $jsonObjects = $object
             switch ( $($i + 1))
            {
              1 { echo "build1=$jsonObjects" >>  $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT}
              2 { echo "build2=$jsonObjects" >>  $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT }           
            }
          }    ## worked

Comment: why not just use `jq` to populate some environment variable for the use?